# Concatenate incremented number on string in array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have this code:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("JEAN.PAUL");
names.add("JEAN.PAUL");
names.add("MARIA.SILVA");
names.add("JEAN.PAUL");
names.add("MARIA.SILVA");
names.add("MARIA.SILVA");
```

I need to increment a number on this names. The expected output should be:

```
System.out.println(names.get(0)) // JEAN.PAUL
System.out.println(names.get(1)) // JEAN.PAUL1
System.out.println(names.get(2)) // MARIA.SILVA
System.out.println(names.get(3)) // JEAN.PAUL2
System.out.println(names.get(4)) // MARIA.SILVA1
System.out.println(names.get(5)) // MARIA.SILVA2
```

I'm ignoring the first one.

I tried so hard but I couldn't do it.
PS: I need it for generic, I have 350.000 names to do it.
I think I need something like, but I don't know how to increment:

```
for (int x=0;x<names.size();x++) {
    for (int z=0;z<names.size();z++) {
        if (names.get(x).equals(names.get(z))) {

        }
    }                       
}
```

Comment: have to modify the list itself? or print it out?

Comment: try harder and you will do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through each element, then look to see what number it should have. Then print out that item with the index after it

```
for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++){
    int index=0;
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(names.get(i).equals(names.get (j)){
             index++;
        }
    }
    if(index==0){
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }else{
        System.out.println(names.get(i) + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: omg, it was so easy and so hard in the same time!.
thank you!

Comment: I was thinking of an complex solution and then you gave the nice and clean solution. good one

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without loops.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class NumberUtil {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private static Map<String, Integer> nameMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        NumberUtil util = new NumberUtil();

        util.function(names, "JEAN.PAUL");
        util.function(names, "JEAN.PAUL");
        util.function(names, "MARIA.SILVA");
        util.function(names, "JEAN.PAUL");
        util.function(names, "MARIA.SILVA");
        util.function(names, "MARIA.SILVA");

        // or read names in loop and call util.function(names,"NAME");

        System.out.println(names);

    }

    private void function(List<String> names, String name) {
        Integer suffix = nameMap.get(name);
        if (suffix == null) {
            nameMap.put(name, Integer.valueOf(1));
            names.add(name);
        } else {
            names.add(name + suffix);
            nameMap.put(name, Integer.valueOf(1) + 1);
        }
    }

}
```